# What order are AWS AutoScaling policies applied in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I am planning on using AWS Autoscaling to scale my EC2 services, I have 4 policies that need to control my instance behavior, 2 for scale out and 2 for scale in. My question is what order will they be evaluated in? Scale out first then scale in? or vice-versa? Random? or something else?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Policies are not evaluated in an order. Each policy is compared against the metrics that policy is set up to measure, and takes actions based on the results.

For example, perhaps you have the following four policies:

1. Add 1 instance when an SQS queue depth is > 1000 messages
2. Remove 1 instance when the same SQS queue depth is < 200 messages
3. Add 1 instance when the average CPU of all instances in the autoscaling group is > 80%
4. Remove 1 instance when the average CPU of all instances in the autoscaling group is < 30%

As you can see, ordering doesn't make sense in this context. The appropriate action(s) will be executed whenever the conditions are met.

Note that without planning and testing you can encounter loops of instances that constantly cycle up and down. Drawing from the previous example, imagine that a new instance is launched because there are > 1000 messages in the queue. But the CPU usage is only 20% for all the instances, so then the 4th policy fires to remove an instance. Thus all the policies should be considered in concert.

Comment: Ben, Thanks for the feedback, this scenario is exactly what I want to avoid. I have policies such that a scale out and scale in could be valid at the same time. What I really want is for the scale out to take precedence over the scale in.

Comment: AFAIK there is no native capability for that. You may find the cooldown period and the ability set a "desired capacity" useful if you decide to roll your own solution.